# Elementary OS install doesn't show up as an option on startup

Tags: system-installation, boot, grub

I made an install drive for Elementary OS (elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200814.iso), but when I restarted my pc, I couldn't select it as an option.  I was unable to get it to show using F1 and F12 keys either.

I got a suggestion to wipe the usb drive and put Elementary OS back on it, but I'm unable to delete the files on the USB, which is a brand new san disk 32 gb w/nothing else on it.

Other context

- using the latest version of KDE Neon User Edition
- on a Lenovo Ideapad 3
- am trying to switch to Elementary OS
- I'm very new to linux and any help is greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

All I had to do was restart.  And then hit F12 BEFORE the GRUB menu showed up, in order to get my bootable drive to show up.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet is full of guides and tools for creating bootable USB drives. You could give Ventoy a try and see how it goes :) https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html
Good luck!